# jqGrid not filling with data?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have set up jqGrid to display my data, even though data is coming from the server, data is not displayed in the grid.
This is the server response.[image: Data is coming from the server like this]

Here is the JavaScript.

```
<table id="Grid1" class="scroll"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;">
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#Grid1").jqGrid({
            url: 'api/matchingservicewebapi/getuser',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Account', 'Ref', 'BDate'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 200 },
                { name: 'Account', index: 'Account', width: 300 },
                { name: 'Ref', index: 'Ref', width: 300 },
                { name: 'BDate', index: 'BDate', width: 300 }

            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'Id',
            viewrecoreds: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            imgpath: 'Themes/images'
        }).navGrid(pager, { edit: true, add: true, del: true, refresh: true, search: true });
});
```

Below is the JSON format of data

```
{"Data":{"rows":[{"id":200.0,"cell":["100","AMX.Data.Account","200","1/10/2010 12:00:00 AM"]},{"id":14726632.0,"cell":["600146","AMX.Data.Account","14726632","1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM"]},{"id":6633000.0,"cell":["668152","AMX.Data.Account","6633000","1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM"]},{"id":2053178.0,"cell":["600146","AMX.Data.Account","2053178","1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM"]},{"id":753550.0,"cell":["668152","AMX.Data.Account","753550","1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM"]},{"id":121774.0,"cell":["600146","AMX.Data.Account","121774","1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM"]},{"id":37900.0,"cell":["600146","AMX.Data.Account","37900","1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM"]},{"id":6569.0,"cell":["668152","AMX.Data.Account","6569","1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM"]},{"id":-1124870617.0,"cell":["668152","AMX.Data.Account","-1124870617","1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM"]},{"id":-813658270.0,"cell":["668152","AMX.Data.Account","-813658270","1/8/2010 12:00:00 AM"]}]},"JsonRequestBehavior":0}
```

But data is not getting loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe i am missing something, but your response json does not include page, total, records, check this link http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid

Comment: Yep, It seems like it must be some problem with the format of your data. Could you paste the json as plain text in the question?

Comment: @txominpelu I added the JSON format data.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments by Mostafa & txominpelu. Try formatting your JSON result as follows

```
{"total":1123,
 "page":1,
 "records":1123,
 "rows":[{"id":1174,
          "cell":["1174","4","",...]
        }]
 }
```

and on the server side

```
public ActionResult GridData(int page, int rows, string searchField = "",
       string searchString = "", string searchOper = "", string sidx = "MY_ID",
       string sord = "desc")
{
    //...
    var jsonData = new {
        total = totalPages,
        page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = (from item in items.ToList()
                select new {
                    id = item.MY_ID,
                    cell = new[] {
                        #region items
                        ToSafeString(item.MY_ID), 
                        ToSafeString(item.ShiftID), 
                        //... 
                        #endregion
                    }
                }).ToArray()
    };
}
```

Comment: should the ID be an int? or is it ok if ID is a string?

Comment: my best guess would be to try it, so far all my id's have been int, but i'm sure string would work as long as its unique. just make sure all the values on the cell object is string